# How to prevent scientific notation in R?

Tags: r

My plot is showing values on the y-axis in the form of e notation. Which command should I use to get the values in the numeric form. The values in the file used are in the numeric form?
Thanks

Comment: What is "e notation"?  Scientific notation?  You can turn it off with `options(scipen = 999)` and back on again with `options(scipen = 0)`

Answer (score 150, accepted):

To set the use of scientific notation in your entire R session, you can use the `scipen` option. From the documentation (`?options`):

```
‘scipen’: integer.  A penalty to be applied when deciding to print
          numeric values in fixed or exponential notation.  Positive
          values bias towards fixed and negative towards scientific
          notation: fixed notation will be preferred unless it is more
          than ‘scipen’ digits wider.
```

So in essence this value determines how likely it is that scientific notation will be triggered. So to prevent scientific notation, simply use a large positive value like `999`:

```
options(scipen=999)
```

Comment: but this adds many traling zeros when doing something like unlist

Answer (score 107):

Try `format` function:

```
> xx = 100000000000
> xx
[1] 1e+11
> format(xx, scientific=F)
[1] "100000000000"
```

Comment: This answer is useful if you don't want to change the global options, as in if you are doing in-line code to report results within the text portion of a .rmd file.