# knitr displaying digits of an integer without scientific notation

Tags: r, knitr

when displaying a number with inline-code with more than four digits like

```
`r 21645`
```

the result in a knitted html-file is this: `2.164510^{4}` (in reality inside the inline-hook there is a calculation going on which results in 21645). Even though I just want it to print the number, like so: `21645`. I can easily fix this for one instance wrapping it inside `as.integer` or `format` or `print`, but how do I set an option for the whole knitr-document so that it prints whole integers as such (all I need is to print 5 digits)? Doing this by hand gets very annoying. Setting `options(digits = 7)` doesnt help. I am guessing I would have to set some chunk-optionor define a [hook](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/), but I have no idea how

Comment: potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946047/how-to-prevent-scientific-notation-in-r (linked to in other answer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that if you type your numeric as integer it will be well formatted:

```
`r 21645L`
```

Of course you can always set an inline hook for more flexibility( even it is better to set globally options as in your answer):

````
```{r}
inline_hook <- function(x) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    format(x, digits = 2)
  } else x
}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline = inline_hook)

```
````

Comment: The first part of your answer I knew, the second part about the hook is interesing, I didnt unterstand how a hook works, now I know, thanks alot! If I understand this correctly the hook only affects how numeric-vectors are displayed and nothing else?

Answer (score 34):

I already solved it, just including the following line of code inside the setoptions-chunk in the beginning of a knitr document:

```
options(scipen=999)
```

resolves the issue, like one can read inside this answer from @Paul Hiemstra:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25947542/4061993

from the documentation of `?options`:

> **scipen**: integer. A penalty to be applied when deciding to print
>   numeric values in fixed or exponential notation. Positive values bias
>   towards fixed and negative towards scientific notation: fixed notation
>   will be preferred unless it is more than scipen digits wider.

Answer (score 24):

If you don't want to display scientific notation in this instance, but also don't want to disable it completely for your `knitr` report, you can use `format()` and set `scientific=FALSE`:

```
`r format(21645, scientific=FALSE)`
```