# Inline code chunk for non-numeric variables in knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to use inline R Markdown code to access the first level of a factor. I can get it to work if I use a chunk but not if I do it inline.

So while this works:

````
```{r}
as.character(iris$Species[1])
```
````

This does not:

```
`r as.character(iris$Species[1])`
```

I could get the inline version to run if I saved the cache and knitted the document twice. I just found this a bit odd because numeric variables behave differently. So, for instance, this works without having to knit it twice

```
`r mean(iris$Sepal.Length)`
```

Comment: can't replicate.  If I create an `rmd` file with *just* your inline code and run it from the console via `rmarkdown::render("inline.rmd")`, it works.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I should have tried it on a clean document before posting here. It turns out I had created an online hook for my inline code to round scientific notation to two digits. I'm not sure why that caused problems for non-numeric variables, but it apparently does.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I found out what the problem was. I found an inline hook that I had taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888631/knitr-displaying-digits-of-an-integer-without-scientific-notation) that turned out to cause the problem:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
inline_hook <- function(x){
    if(is.numeric(x)){
      paste(format(x,digits = 2))
    }
   }
knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline=inline_hook)
```
````