# How to interpolate variable values in R markdown documents

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is it possible to interpolate R code or variable values in R markdown documents? I mean something like:

````
---
title: "Behavioural report"
author: "My name"
date: "Some date here"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
X = 1.28473
```

Suppose that this is my R markdown document and I want to say that the value
of the variable X = {Here I want the value of X to appear}. And then blah...
````

So I want the value 1.28473 to appear just after the text 'X ='.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following in place of your `{}`

```
`r X`
```

You can also do inline computations:

```
`r mean(rnorm(50))`
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I'm doing that and getting some weird scientific notation or something. My markdown says `m = \`r m\``, (m == 33634), and it renders as `m = 3.363410^{4}`

Comment: Here's the answer to my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946047/how-to-prevent-scientific-notation-in-r