# Import a .csv with large numbers into R without scientific notation

Tags: r, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I have a Microsoft Excel (.xlsx) file which I would like to load into R. I've done this before and used `read.csv()`, which always worked fine, but with this file something strange happens. Something seems to go wrong with one column, which contains a row name and large numbers with values of 13 digits. This column is - no matter how I try to load the file into R - converted to its scientific notation.

The problem can be simulated as follows: in Excel, type in the first column first 
row, a random row name. Type in the first column second row a random big number, e.g. 6345157890027. Then save the file as .csv. Let's suppose I want to open this file in R:
`TestData <- read.csv(file = "Test.csv", head = TRUE)` and then
`View(TestData)`

The number 6345157890027 is now displayed as 6.345158e+12, and information is lost somewhere during import. Now, I've tried to solve this multiple ways:

- In both the .xlsx and the .csv file, I converted the row
  into number format
- Tried all .csv formats that Excel allows me to save it in
- Copied the whole worksheet to a new Excel file
- Used the Import Data function in Excel
- Save the worksheet as .txt and import this into R using File->Import Dataset function

However, none of these solved the problem: the value always seems to appear in scientific notation. Does someone knows a way to make sure either Excel or R does not transform large numbers into scientific notation?

Comment: Are you sure you are losing information?  What happens when you use `print(..., digits = 15)`

Comment: You are right, the information is not lost, it's just displayed differently. However, still I would like like to be able to display the information as a whole number.

Comment: Use `options(digits = 15)`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But I should clarify myself: I see that with using this option, it is possible to display the value in the R console in the non-scientific manner. However, when I use for example ```View(TestData)``` I still see the scientific notation. Is there a way to overcome this, it would make things more convenient for me

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example where it does not work. This works for me to produce all digits: `options(digits = 15);
DF <- data.frame(x = 6345157890027);
View(DF)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the `format` function, as proposed in another post by [rnso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3522130/rnso) (see [How to prevent scientific notation in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946047/how-to-prevent-scientific-notation-in-r/25946211)):

```
> xx = 100000000000
> xx
[1] 1e+11
> format(xx, scientific=F)
[1] "100000000000"
```

Also worked perfectly for my wrongly displayed column in my data frame

Answer (score 1):

One can just declare `options(scipen = 999)` and make sure that the environment does not change large numbers to exponential form.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `as.bit64` function from the `bit64`  package. Just make sure to not use 64bit numbers to reference other R objects. This solutions is good for numbers found in the `+-2^63` range.

Comment: If you haven’t lost any information as your other comment states then this solution will not help you. Your numbers are not big enough to need 64bit storage.