# disable scientific notation when using pipes and mutate function

Tags: r

im trying to pass a dataframe through some pipes in order to calculate a division. the result shows in scientific notation, which i dont want.
Is there a way to disable it on the pipe function?

```
df=structure(list(E_CodTecEntregado = "20029235-02", E_CantTotEntregada = "28", 
F_ValorUnitFacturado = 6071, F_ValorTotFacturado = 169988, 
F_FecFacturacion = structure(18610, class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df= df %>% 
  mutate (PrecioUnitario = (F_ValorTotFacturado / as.numeric(E_CantTotEntregada)))
```

[image]

Comment: May be this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946047/how-to-prevent-scientific-notation-in-r/25946211

Comment: `options(scipen = 999)` should do that.