# How can I display values without using scientific notation, with the programming language r?

Tags: r, decimal

| with e | without e |
| --- | --- |
| 1.754429e+01 | 17.54429 |
| 1.529317e+01 | 15.29317 |

Comment: Display in what context? Printing in the console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946047/how-to-prevent-scientific-notation-in-r