# Formatting a monetary amount to avoid scientific notation

Tags: r, format

I would like to format a monetary amount with two decimal places, a comma "," as a decimal separator and a point "." as a thousands separator. I am using

```
format(160000,nsmall=2,big.interval=3,big.mark=".",decimal.mark=",",format="f")
[1] "160.000,00"
```

The result looks exactly the way I want it. However, for a different number, I again get scientific notation using the same code:

```
format(200000,nsmall=2,big.interval=3,big.mark=".",decimal.mark=",",format="f")
[1] "2e+05"
```

Can somebody explain this behavior to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem. One option is to set `scientific = FALSE` in your `format()`, e.g.

```r
format(160000,nsmall=2,big.interval=3,big.mark=".",decimal.mark=",",format="f")
#> [1] "160.000,00"
format(200000,nsmall=2,big.interval=3,big.mark=".",decimal.mark=",",format="f")
#> [1] "2e+05"
format(200000,nsmall=2,big.interval=3,big.mark=".",decimal.mark=",",format="f", scientific = FALSE)
#> [1] "200.000,00"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Another option is to modify `scipen()`, e.g.

```r
format(160000,nsmall=2,big.interval=3,big.mark=".",decimal.mark=",",format="f")
#> [1] "160.000,00"
format(200000,nsmall=2,big.interval=3,big.mark=".",decimal.mark=",",format="f")
#> [1] "2e+05"
options(scipen = 999)
format(200000,nsmall=2,big.interval=3,big.mark=".",decimal.mark=",",format="f")
#> [1] "200.000,00"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

There are many explanations of this behaviour online, e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-prevent-scientific-notation-in-r/ / [How to prevent scientific notation in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946047/how-to-prevent-scientific-notation-in-r) / [How can I disable scientific notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-can-i-disable-scientific-notation)

NB. if this doesn't solve your problem (especially if I've misunderstood!), please post a comment and I can further clarify and/or your question can be reopened